# Spring MVC - 5.2.9.RELEASE with Mongo (spring-data-mongodb - 3.0.4.RELEASE) not working

Tags: spring, mongodb

**While configuring the Mongo DB with Spring MVC (5.2.9.RELEASE) and deploying it to Tomcat 9.5 as WAR file it is giving me the follow error:**

```
Below is the stacktrace:
Many thanks, I was able to resolve that, but now it is showing me error Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT with the pom entry:<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is my configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd       
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd">
<mongo:mongo-client id="mongoClient" host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
        <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" dbname="mydocs" mongo-ref="mongoClient"/>
        <!-- <mongo:db-factory id="mongoDbFactory" host="127.0.0.1" port="27017"  dbname="mydocs" username="" password=""/> -->
        
        
        <mongo:mapping-converter id="converter" db-factory-ref="mongoDbFactory"/>

    <bean name="gridFsTemplate"
        class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.gridfs.GridFsTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoDbFactory" />
        <constructor-arg ref="converter" />
    </bean>
```

And I am using the mongodb dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.7</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Please advice how to resolve the issue

Comment: Error message states `mongo-ref` is not allowed in `<mongo:db-factory>`

Comment: Use `<mongo:db-factory mongo-client-ref="…​" />` instead since `mongo-ref` has been replaced in 3.x

Answer (score 1):

Error message states mongo-ref is not allowed in mongo:db-factory. So use `<mongo:db-factory mongo-client-ref="…​" />` instead since `mongo-ref` has been replaced in 3.x. Read more at [Removed XML Namespace Elements & Attributes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#reference)

Comment: Many thanks, I was able to resolve that, but now it is showing me error Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT